# How do I identify all .txt files in a directory and subdirectories in Python?

Tags: python, loops, file, directory

I am trying to loop through all .txt files in a file directory that contains a bunch of subdirectories. The .txt files are in the subdirectories. Here is what I have in a .py so far:

```
import os
import csv
import re

csv_cont = []
directory = os.getcwd()
for root,dir,files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:

        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            f = open(file, 'r')
            file_content = f.read()

            
            title = re.search('Title:(.*)', file_content)
            if title:
                if title.group(1):
                    title = title.group(1)
                else:
                    title = "\n"
```

The issue with this is that I don't have .txt files in the directory, so I need to put the above Python file in the subdirectory with the text files for the above code to work. I want to be able to loop from the directory and go through every subdirectory. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Use the `glob` module: `glob.glob("parent_dir/**/*.txt", recursive=True)` will yield a list of strings, where each string is a path to a text file.

Comment: chnage the line directory = getcwd() to make directory the directory you want

Comment: Where in my code do I have to make a change? I tried both solutions and neither worked.

Answer (score 1):

This worked:

```
import os
import csv
import re
import glob

csv_cont = []
for file in glob.glob('**/*.txt', recursive=True):

        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            f = open(file, 'r')
            file_content = f.read()

            
            title = re.search('Title:(.*)', file_content)
            if title:
                if title.group(1):
                    title = title.group(1)
                else:
                    title = "\n"
```